# In MeteorJS, how to send SMS verification OTP code?

Tags: meteor

In MeteorJS, how to send SMS verification OTP code?. Is there any package?. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `okland:accounts-phone` for this. However, if you are not using twilio, you will have to write your own code according to the provider in the method highlighted in the documentation.